# Strange behaviour of UITableViewCell content layout when the table is resized with animation

Tags: ios

I am trying to create a view hierarchy with a menu that would 'slide out' from the left side of the screen when the user pulls the slider. The menu is implemented as a table with a bunch of cells. Each cell has an image and a text. I am animating the change to the table size. As I am using autolayout, here is my code:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController {
    CGFloat size;//0 .. self.frame.size.width * drawerPortion
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;
    UITableViewController *tableViewController;
}

// ...
@end

@implementation MyController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
//...
    UIView *view = tableViewController.view;
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:nil
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                   multiplier:1
                                                     constant:0];
    [view addConstraint:constraint];

    [self redrawTable];

}

- (void)makeDrawerVisible:(BOOL)visible {
    size = visible ? 224 : 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                     animations:^{[self redrawTable];}
                 }];
 }

- (void)redrawTable {
    constraint.constant = size;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}


// ...
@end
```

The `tableViewController` is a pretty basic textbook implementation of `UITableViewController`. The cells are created as follows:

```
UITableCell *cell = [[UITableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Loren ipsum";
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"group"];
```

Initially, after I launch the app, the menu is created with zero width and is therefore hidden. When I then pull the slider, the whole thing animates nicely to the specified width (224). Here are the screenshots from my emulator, the view in the middle of the animation an the final result.

[image: middle of animation - correct] 
[image: final result of animation]

The weird thing starts happening after I animate the table back to size zero. The text on the labels slides to the left and becomes partly obscured by the images. Here is how it looks:

[image: middle of animation - incorrect]

From this moment onwards, as long as I animate the menu back and forth I keep observing this nasty effect. Has anyone encountered similar issues? Is there any way to prevent the labels from repositioning during animation? Any pointers to good documentation on how subviews are re-laid-out during superview animation will also be appreciated. I've been banging my head against this issue for some days already and found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints and/or resizing masks are doing it to you. Instead of doing constraint manipulation put the slide menu behind the black view and then transform the main view (in this case the black one back and forth) example

```
if(isOpening)
{
    mainView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(mainView.transform, someValueToShiftRight, 0.0f);
}
else
{
    mainView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

Comment: This workaround will not work for me. I need the menu to slide out on top of the background view. Otherwise features on the right hand side of the menu (the margin) will not be displayed properly.

Regarding the constraints and masks - it would be interesting to get more info on this. There are no constraints whatsoever under the `UITableViewCell` hierarchy (I am logging them). The `autoresizingMask` on the text label is zero by default, but setting it to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` does not make any difference.